Integral of $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ over $|z-(1+i)|=1$
I want to compute $$\oint_{|z-(1+i)|=1} \operatorname{Log}(z) \, dz$$ naturally choosing the principal branch
$$
\operatorname{Log}(z):=\log|z|+i\operatorname{Arg} (z)\ 
$$
From where $$\operatorname{Arg} (z) \in \ ]{-\pi},\pi[$$ we can parameterize the curve $|z-(1+i)|=1$ because it is a circle, center of which lies on $z=(1+i)$, with that we could use the definition of line integral. Also, I have thought that we could use Cauchy–Goursat theorem. We know that the function $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ is analytic everywhere except at the value of $z=0$ and I think, that the value of $z=0$ does not belong to the region over which we are integrating, so it is analytical on that disk, hence
$$
\oint_{|z-(1+i)|=1} \operatorname{Log}(z) \, dz =0
$$
Any suggestions or help on how to calculate this integral?

The integral is indeed equal to $0$, by the reasons you have given (just a small nitpick, the logarithm is analytic except for a ray, in this case, the negative real axis)

Of course the integral is zero as deduced by you and reiterated in the comments,  by Cauchy's theorem.
The nearest singularity of the integrand,  $\log z,$ is at $0.$
But $\mid (1+i)-0)\mid =\sqrt2 \gt1.$
So the function is holomorphic/analytic on $\mid z-(1+i)\mid \le1.$

Put slightly differently,  $\log z$ has a power series centered at $1+i$ which converges on $\mid z-(1+i)\mid \lt\sqrt2. $
So Cauchy's theorem is all systems go.
